# Integrating Reddit Login

Tags: android, reddit

I am trying to integrate Reddit login. I am reading this link "https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2"

I want to make an app similar to Reddit (I can display subreddits of subscriber, friends, etc). During creating the application I have selected installed apps. I am getting to authorization page using this little code but I am only getting "**code**" and "**status**" in my redirect URL. How to get **access_token** so that I can get user history, upvotes, subreddits, etc?

```
String url = "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=m************A&response_type=code&state=\"arpit\"&redirect_uri=https://utkarshgithub.github.io/nearby/&duration=permanent&scope=history";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: did you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20151937/3678308 ??

Comment: yes i looked at it , but didnt get where and how to use that . I have used google login , it was easy and simple ,but reddit login is different. And no where in the reddit api documentation it is written to use "raw4j reddit api wrapper " so why it is required

Comment: There are two separate questions here, and the presence of the second one makes things more confusing. I think it would be better to remove the second one, so that people do not believe it is too broad (and thus off-topic).